# How to remove -EE warning about a deprecated function from the NCE LDAP plugin

Tags: add-on, add-on-development

The system has detected an add-on that is using outdated code that may stop working or cause issues with the system. **What does this means and how can I solve the issue?**

> Deprecated function hash() called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet3\system\expressionengine\third_party\nce_ldap\ext.nce_ldap.php
>   on line 265. Deprecated since 2.0. Use Security_helper::do_hash
>   instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the hash() function line with following code:

```
$this->EE->load->helper('security');
$encrypted_password = do_hash(stripslashes($user_info['password']));
```